# Minimum number of steps to convert the matrix by swapping

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I stumbled upon the below question and was unable to solve it, can someone tell whats the approach here[image]

Comment: Please post the text or a link to it.

Comment: The link's expired, dont have the text :)

Comment: for eg the matrix: [[7,3,2],[4,1,5],[6,8,9]] gives the output 6. 
[[7,3,2],[4,1,5],[6,8,9]] -> [[4,3,2],[7,1,5],[6,8,9]] -> [[4,3,2],[6,1,5],[7,8,9]] -> [[4,3,2],[1,6,5],[7,8,9]] -> [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this except by brute force, recursively.  For each tile that's not in the right position, there are at most 4 possible swaps to make.  You make a swap, then add this new position to the list of ones you haven't tried, making sure not to go back to any position you've seen before.  Track the depth of the recursion, and when you get a final position, the depth is the answer.

```
incoming = (7,3,2,4,1,5,6,8,9)
answer = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
primes = (2,3,5,7,11,13,17)

def solve(base, depth):
    seen = set()
    untried = [(base,0)]

    while untried:
        array,depth = untried.pop(0)
        print(depth, array)
        if array == answer:
            print( "ANSWER!", depth )
            return depth
        if array in seen:
            print("seen")
            continue
        seen.add( array )

        for n in range(9):
            if array[n] == n+1:
                continue
            for dx in (-1, -3, 1, 3):
                if 0 <= n+dx < 9 and array[n]+array[n+dx] in primes:
                    # attempt a swap.
                    a = list(array)
                    a[n],a[n+dx] = a[n+dx],a[n]
                    untried.append((tuple(a),depth+1))
    print( "fail" )
    return -1
                
solve( incoming, 0 )
```